Weak convergence for complex random variables
Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, Y_1, Y_2, \dots$ be sequences of real random variables, and let $X$ and $Y$ be further random variables. Suppose that $X_n$ is independent of $Y_n$ for each $n$, and $X$ independent of $Y$. Show that $X_n + iY_n$ converges in distribution to $X + iY$ if and only if $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ and $Y_n$ converges to distribution to $Y$.
It is stated that the shortest way to prove this is by invoking the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. Here I record a proof by proving the two-dimensional version of the following fact: Namely, if $X_1, X_2, \dots$ is a sequence of real random variables, and $X$ another real random variable, then $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ if and only if $F_{X_n}(t)$ converges to $F_X(t)$ for each continuity point $t$ of $F_X$. Here $F_X(t) := {\bf P}(X \leq t)$ is the distribution function of $X$. Verifications are appreciated.

Let $Z_n = X_n + iY_n, X = X + iY$. Identifying $\bf C$ with ${\bf R}^2$, we define $F_{Z}: {\bf C} \rightarrow [0, 1]$ to be the function $F_Z((t_1, t_2)) := \mu_{Z}((-\infty, t_1] \times (-\infty, t_2]) = F_{X}(t_1) \cdot F_{Y}(t_2)$ (from independence).
Suppose that $F_{X_n}(t_1) \rightarrow F_X(t_1)$ for each continuity point $t_1$ of $F_X$, and $F_{Y_n}(t_2) \rightarrow F_Y(t_2)$ for each continuity point $t_2$ of $F_Y$. Let $G: {\bf C} \rightarrow {\bf R}$ be a continuous compactly supported function, then it is uniformly continuous. As $F_X$ and $F_Y$ are monotone increasing, they can only have countably many points of discontinuity, hence $F_Z$ can only have countably many points of discontinuity. From these two facts one can find, for any $\varepsilon>0$, a simple function $G_{\varepsilon}(z) = \sum_{1 \leq i, j \leq n} c_{ij}1_{[t_i, t_{i+1}) \times [s_j, s_{j+1})}$ for some $t_1 < \dots < t_n$ that are points of continuity of $F_X$, and $s_1 < \dots < s_n$ that are points of continuity of $F_Y$, with real numbers $c_{ij}$, such that ${|G(z) - G_\varepsilon(z)| \leq \varepsilon}$ for all $z \in {\bf C}$. Thus
$\displaystyle {\bf E}G(Z_n) = {\bf E}G_{\varepsilon}(Z_n) + O(\varepsilon) = \sum_{1 \leq i, j \leq n} c_{ij}[F_{X_n}(t_{i+1}) - F_{X_n}(t_i)][F_{Y_n}(s_{j+1}) - F_{Y_n}(s_j)] + O(\varepsilon)$.
Similarly for ${X_n}$ replaced by ${X}$. Subtracting and taking limit superior, we conclude that
$\displaystyle \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} |{\bf E}G(Z_n) - {\bf E}G(Z)| = O(\varepsilon)$,
and on sending ${\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}$, we obtain that ${Z_n}$ converges in distribution to ${Z}$. In particular, if ${X_n} \rightarrow {X}$ in distribution and ${Y_n} \rightarrow {Y}$ in distribution, then $Z_n \rightarrow Z$ in distribution.
Conversely, suppose that $Z_n \rightarrow Z$ in distribution, and $F_X$ is continuous at $t_1$. For any ${\varepsilon > 0}$, one can find a ${\delta}$ such that
$\displaystyle F_X(t_1) - \varepsilon \leq F_X(t') \leq F_X(t_1) + \varepsilon$ for every ${t' \in [t-\delta,t+\delta]}$.
Fix a continuity point $t_2$ of $F_Y$ large enough with $\displaystyle F_Y(t_2) \geq 1 - \varepsilon$. One can now find $N > \max(|t_1|+\delta, |t_2|+\delta)$ such that ${F_X(-N) \leq \varepsilon}$ and ${F_X(N) \geq 1-\varepsilon}$, and similarly ${F_Y(-N) \leq \varepsilon}$ and ${F_Y(N) \geq 1-\varepsilon}$. Thus
$\displaystyle {\bf P} (|X| \geq N ) = O(\varepsilon)$ and $\displaystyle {\bf P} (|X - t| \leq \delta ) = O(\varepsilon)$
and similarly
$\displaystyle {\bf P} (|Y| \geq N ) = O(\varepsilon)$ and $\displaystyle {\bf P} (|Y - t| \leq \delta ) = O(\varepsilon)$.
Let $G: {\bf C} \rightarrow [0, 1]$ be a continuous function supported on $[-2N, t_1] \times [-2N, t_2]$ that equals $1$ on $[-N, t_1 - \delta] \times [-N, t_2 - \delta]$. Then by the above discussion we have $\displaystyle {\bf E}G(Z) = F_X(t_1)F_Y(t_2) + O(\varepsilon)$, and hence $\displaystyle {\bf E}G(Z_n) = F_X(t_1)F_Y(t_2) + O(\varepsilon)$ for large enough $n$. In particular
$\displaystyle {\bf P}(X_n \leq t_1) \geq F_X(t_1)F_Y(t_2) - O(\varepsilon) \geq F_X(t_1) - O(\varepsilon)$
A similar argument, replacing ${G}$ with a continuous function supported on $[t_1, 2N] \times [t_2, 2N]$ that equals $1$ on $[t_1+\delta, N] \times [t_2+\delta, N]$ gives
$\displaystyle {\bf P}(X_n > t_1) \geq 1 - F_X(t_1)F_Y(t_2) - O(\varepsilon) \geq 1 - F_X(t_1) - O(\varepsilon)$
for $n$ large enough. Putting the two estimates together gives
$\displaystyle F_{X_n}(t) = F_X(t) + O(\varepsilon)$
for ${n}$ large enough; sending ${\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}$, we obtain that $X_n \rightarrow X$ in distribution. Reversing the role of $X_n$ and $Y_n$, we obtain the claim.
